# google image search problems in android

Tags: image, search, android-intent

I like to perform google image search on my android phone (htc evo). My source code:

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"));
   startActivity(browserIntent);

The search works fine on my desktop but keeps showing http://www.google.com/wenhp?.......and nothing else. Note that it works if google text search is carried out.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some nice Example Codes that you can take help from.

Android Image Search https://github.com/tonytamsf/Android-Image-Search

Grid Image Search App Android https://github.com/adi2188/gridImageSearchApp

I hope this solves your problem.